# how to get main category

Tags: php, mysql

In `add_article.php` I've main category and subcategory.
How to get subcategory only to add article?

[image: Table]

Comment: Do you want to get all leaves?

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT catID,catName 
FROM cats 
where catparent <> NULL AND catID NOT IN (SELECT catparent FROM cats)`

The above code will give only those subcategory whuch has no child cat.

If you want to get all subcat than simply use select query with where parent not equal to NULL